# I am fetching data from api in react using useeffect hook.But its getting called multiple times.But i need to call it once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch-api

I am fetching data from api in react using useeffect hook.But its getting called multiple times.But i need to call it once.Can anyone tell how to achieve that?

I tried using useeffect hook

```
 const getData = () => {
    fetch("https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/capital")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        scname(data.data);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: The useEffect hook you have will run once for every time that component is mounted. I suggest that you [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), and check if the data has already been fetched in your hook before calling getData.

Comment: Are you using React strict mode?

Comment: @shamaliroshan Thanks..I removed the strict mode.Now its working as expected